# Can we explain why using `Nothing` twice on a list does not operate twice?

Tags: functions

Below I generate a list of numbers between 1 and 15. I then set the value at position 10 to `Nothing` and as expected the value at position 10 is changed. This is as expected.

```
   In[1]:= b = Range[15]
b[[10]] = Nothing;
b
b[[10]]

Out[1]= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}

Out[3]= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}

Out[4]= 11
```

So far so good. However, if I do this again then nothing happens, the list is unaltered. I was expecting to have the value now at position 10 removed.

```
In[5]:= b[[10]] = Nothing;
b
b[[10]]

Out[6]= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}

Out[7]= 11
```

Can anyone explain this? Thanks

"13.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)"

Comment: Oh that is strange. You can continue the process: do `b[[9]] = Nothing; Print[b]; b[[9]] = Nothing; b` and the same thing happens. But perhaps `Nothing` is not meant to be used this way?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Take a look at `Definition[b]`.

```
b = Range[15];
Definition[b]
(* b={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15} *)

b[[10]] = Nothing;
Definition[b]
(* b={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,Nothing,11,12,13,14,15} *)
```

When you set element 10 to `Nothing`, the list retains its shape, just its definition changes so that the 10th element is `Nothing`. Whenever symbol `b` is then used (evaluated), this `Nothing` gets stripped away.

```
Trace[b] // Column
(* b
   {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,Nothing,11,12,13,14,15}
   {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15} *)

Trace[b[[10]]] // Column
(* {b,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,Nothing,11,12,13,14,15},{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15}}
   {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15}[[10]]
   11 *)
```

Comment: A very useful and informative analysis. The `Trace[b[[10]]]`is particular revealing about how things work. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

[Based on the timestamp, it looks like Domen's answer has priority. I'm leaving my answer, because I think it adds some extra flavor, but I don't think there is sufficient reason for these answers to be in competition. I.e. if one of these is to be selected as "the answer", it should be Domen's based on priority.]

Look at `Information["b"]`. I'm assuming that this is working as expected. The token `Nothing` is just an expression like everything else. It just gets interpreted specially when it's in a list. So, when you evalute `b[[10]] = Nothing`, you are literally assigning the 10th element of `b` to `Nothing`. Now, whenever you subsequently *evaluate* `b`, that `Nothing` gets interpreted and the result is a list that's missing the `10`.

You could re-assign the 10th element of `b` if you want (you actually did this, you just re-used the same value though):

```
b = Range[15]
```

`{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}`

```
b[[10]] = Nothing;
b
```

`{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}`

```
b[[10]] = 99999;
b
```

`{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 99999, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}`

Interestingly, if you evaluated `b = b` at some point, this would change the actual definition of `b` to be a list without the `Nothing`s.

**UPDATE**

I thought it would be worth explicitly showing the `b = b` evaluation, because I think that might clarify some issues that have come up in comments. So, from the top:

```
b = Range[15]
```

`{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}`

```
b[[10]] = Nothing;
OwnValues[b]
```

`{HoldPattern[b] :> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, Nothing, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}}`

```
Length[b]
```

`14` <- This is because `b` was evaluated, and during evaluation `Nothing` was removed.

```
(OwnValues[b] /. List -> Hold)[[1, 2]]
```

`Hold[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, Nothing, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]`

```
Length@%
```

`15` <- The point here is `Nothing` doesn't affect the computation of `Length`.

```
b = b
```

`{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}` <- The right hand side was evaluated, and the result of that evaluation was assigned to `b`. We can then see that `b` has indeed changed:

```
OwnValues[b]
```

`{HoldPattern[b] :> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}}`

Comment: These extra investigations are helpful. I am not clear of the effect on PackedArrays. Is that also worth exploring?